# Quarkus, Heroku and different environments

Tags: vue.js, heroku, environment-variables, quarkus

I'm currently developing a simple webapp with seperated frontend (Vue) and backend (quarkus REST API) project. For now, I've setup a MVP, where the frontend is displaying some simple data which is called from the backend. To get a working MVP i need to setup CORS support. However, first i want to explain my setup:

#### Setup

I'm starting developing environment of my frontend with `npm run serve` and of my backend with `./mvnw quarkus:dev`. Frontend is running on `localhost:8081` and backend running on `localhost:8080`. 
Heroku allows to run your apps locally aswell with the command `heroku local web`. Frontend is running on port `0.0.0.0:5001` and backend on `0.0.0.0:5000`.

To achieve this setup i setup two `.env` files on my frontend which are pointing to my backend api. If i want to work in development mode the file `.env.development` is loaded:

```
VUE_APP_ROOT_API=http://localhost:8080
```

and if i run `heroku local web` the file `.env.local` with

```
VUE_APP_ROOT_API=0.0.0.0:5000
```

is loaded.

In my backend I've set 
`quarkus.http.cors=true`
in my `application.properties`.

Now I want to deploy those two projects to heroku and use it in production. Therefore I setup two heroku projects and set a config variable in my frontend project with the following value:

```
VUE_APP_ROOT_API:https://mybackend.herokuapp.com
```

Calls from my frontend are successfully working!

#### Question

For the next step, I want to restrict it more and just enable my frontend to call my API. I know i can set something like

```
quarkus.http.cors.origins=myfrontend.herokuapp.com
```

However, I dont know how i could do this on quarkus with different environments (development, local and production)? I've found this  [link](https://quarkus.io/guides/config#configuration-profiles) but I don't know how to configure heroku and my backend app correctly. Do i need to setup different profiles which are applied on my different environments? Or is there another solution? Do i need Herokus Config Variables?

Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`quarkus.http.cors.origins` is overridable at runtime so you have several possibilities.

You could use a profile and have everything set up in your `application.properties` with `%prod.quarkus.http.cors.origins=...`. Then you either use `-Dquarkus.profile=prod` when launching your application or you use `QUARKUS_PROFILE=prod` as an environment variable.

Another option is to use an environment variable for `quarkus.http.cors.origins`. That would be `QUARKUS_HTTP_CORS_ORIGINS=...`.

My recommendation would be to use a profile. That way you can safely check that all your configuration is consistent at a glance.